# How i change this to looping or short version?

Tags: delphi, loops, checkbox, delphi-7

I have the following code. How can I simplify this, using looping or a different shorter version?

```
if checkbox1.Checked = true then
    begin
      a := 1;
    end
   else
      begin
      a := 0;
      end;
    if checkbox2.Checked = true then
      begin
      b := 1;
      end
    else
      begin
      b := 0;
      end ;
    if checkbox3.Checked = true then
      begin
      c := 1;
      end
    else
      begin
      c := 0;
      end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a := Ord(Checkbox1.Checked);
b := Ord(Checkbox2.Checked);
c := Ord(Checkbox3.Checked);
```

If you want to use a loop:

```
private
  Values: array[0..2] of Integer;
  CheckBoxes: array[0..2] of TCheckBox;
```

```
CheckBoxes[0] := CheckBox1;
CheckBoxes[1] := CheckBox2;
CheckBoxes[2] := CheckBox3;
```

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 2 do
    Values := Ord(CheckBoxes[I].Checked);
end;
```